# How to implement confirmation or preview in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I am calling JSON api from my rails app. User inputs a name in a form, Then i call JSON API and find if the name has any matches there. Sometimes its just one so i create entry with the data provided in JSON. But most of the times there are multiple results on the JSON, How do i implement "Hey i found multiple results for same name, which one were you looking for?" and then the users chooses which one he/she was intending and then it creates an entry in database.

I wrote a simple script to test out the JSON.

```
data = JSON.load response

if data['results'].empty?
  #if the JSON data is empty
  puts "There was no movie found. Did you spell the movie name correctly?"
elsif data['results'].count > 1
  #if JSON Data has more than one result
  data['results'].each do |movie|
    Movie::Movies << Movie.new(movie['id'],
                      movie['title'],
                      movie['release_year'],
                      (imdb_url + movie['imdb']).to_s,
                      movie['rating'],
                      movie['poster_120x171'],
                      movie['poster_240x342'],
                      movie['poster_400x570'])
    end
    Movie::Movies.each do |movie|
      puts "#{movie.title} : #{movie.release_year}"
  end
else
  #IF JSON has only one entry
    movie = Movie.new(data['results'][0]['id'],
                      data['results'][0]['title'],
                      data['results'][0]['release_year'],
                      (imdb_url + data['results'][0]['imdb']).to_s,
                      data['results'][0]['rating'],
                      data['results'][0]['poster_120x171'],
                      data['results'][0]['poster_240x342'],
                      data['results'][0]['poster_400x570'])
end
```

And here is my controller at the moment. It can only handle the first record from the Hash provided by JSON. I have no clue on how to handle the situation if there are multiple results.

```
  def create
        require 'rest_client'
        require 'json'
        imdb_url = 'http://www.imdb.com/title/'
        movie_title = movie_params['title'].delete(' ')
        response = RestClient.get "http://api-public.guidebox.com/v1.43/US/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx<api-key>/search/movie/title/#{movie_title}"
        data = JSON.load response
        @movie = Movie.new #i am doing this because my for was giving error.
        if data['results'].empty?
            flash[:alert] = "Did you spell the Title correctly? Or Maybe we could not find the movie you are looking for."
            render 'new'
       elsif data['results'].count > 2
       #Display all results to the user for them to pick what they really intended and create an entry of whaterver they choose.
        else
            @movie = Movie.new(gb_id: data['results'][0]['id'],
                               title: data['results'][0]['title'],
                               release_year: data['results'][0]['release_year'],
                               imdb_link: (imdb_url + data['results'][0]['imdb']).to_s,
                               rating: data['results'][0]['rating'],
                               small_img: data['results'][0]['poster_120x171'],
                               med_img: data['results'][0]['poster_240x342'],
                               large_img: data['results'][0]['poster_400x570'])
            if @movie.save
                flash[:notice] = 'Movie has been successfully Added.'
                redirect_to @movie
            else
                flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong. Please try again."
                render 'new'
            end
      end
    end
```

Also in my create action i had to call the `@movie = Movie.new` again because the form was giving me errors.

Comment: This is getting pretty unruly in terms of organization. Move your `require` calls to the top of the file, those don't belong inside a method. Keep indentation constant and clean.

Comment: Normally the pattern to use is `@movie.save!` and then rescue `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid`.

Answer (score 0):

You are close - to allow user to disambiguate results, do something similar to what you have in the else clause, but in a loop, using a separate action.

```
# controller
def create
  #...
  if data['results'].empty?
              flash[:alert] = "Did you spell the Title correctly? Or Maybe we could not find the movie you are looking for."
              render 'new'
  elsif data['results'].count > 1
    @movie_choices = []
    data['results'].each_with_index do |result, idx|
      @movie_choices << Movie.new(gb_id: data['results'][idx]['id'],
                         title: data['results'][idx]['title'] #, ...

    end
    render 'movies/choose_movie'
  else
    @movie = Movie.new(gb_id: data['results'][0]['id'],
                       title: data['results'][0]['title'],
                       release_year: data['results'][0]['release_year'],
                       imdb_link: (imdb_url + data['results'][0]['imdb']).to_s,
                       rating: data['results'][0]['rating'],
                       small_img: data['results'][0]['poster_120x171'],
                       med_img: data['results'][0]['poster_240x342'],
                       large_img: data['results'][0]['poster_400x570'])
    if @movie.save
        flash[:notice] = 'Movie has been successfully Added.'
        redirect_to @movie
    else
        flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong. Please try again."
        render 'new'
    end
  end
end

def movie_chosen
  chosen_movie_gb_id = params[:movie_gb_id] 
  @movie = Movie.new(gb_id: params[:movie_id],
                     title: params[:movie_title],
                     # ...
                     )
  if @movie.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Movie has been successfully Added.'
      redirect_to @movie
  else
      flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong. Please try again."
      render 'new'
  end
end

# app/views/movies/choose_movie.html.erb
<%= form_tag 'movies/movie_chosen' do %>
  <div>
    <% @movie_choices.each do |mc| %>
      <div>
        <%= radio_button_tag :movie_id, mc.gb_id %> <%= mc.title %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :movie_title, mc.title %>
        <!-- ... other fields of the movie object -->
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```